# lua metatables - first parameter in __index function

Tags: lua, metatable

I'm trying to learn metatables in Lua and I came across the following example: -

```
local my_metatable = {}

local my_tab = {}

setmetatable(my_tab, my_metatable)

-- Set the __index metamethod:
my_metatable.__index = function (tab, key)
    print("Hello, " .. key)
    return "cruel world"
end

-- Trigger the __index metamethod:
print("Goodbye, " .. my_tab["world"])
```

The result is:-

```
Hello, world
Goodbye, cruel world
```

My question is - what does the variable `tab` do, in `my_metatable.__index = function (tab, key)`. I can change it to anything and it doesn't affect the program in any way.

Thanks!

;^)
Zalokin

Comment: You can't learn if whenever you encounter any difficulty you don't Google for it yourself and lazily ask it on StackOverflow. Also on all question you have your name right under it so a signature is unnecessary.

Comment: You can use the same metamethod (or the same metatable) for several tables   The variable `tab` will be equal to the table which is being indexed.

Comment: it is actually explained in the Lua manual. Would you please just refer to it befor asking questions here? Thank you.(that's the only way you'll ever learn to program on your own)

Answer (score 0):

The `tab` parameter is passed an argument of the table itself.

For example, given your code `my_tab["world"]`, the parameters `tab` and `key` will be passed the arguments `my_tab` and `"world"` respectively. Because you didn't use the table in your `__index` function, it didn't affect anything.

Here is a basic example of what it might be used for. Let us consider a special Array table that acts like an array but has some additional information:

```
Array = {
    length = 0,
    array = {}
}

mt = {
    __index = function(tab, index)
        return tab.array[index]
    end
}

setmetatable(t, mt)

--now when Array[3] is written, what will actually be returned is Array.array[3]

print(Array[3]) --will actually print Array.array[3]
```

This isn't actually the best way to implement this functionality, but hopefully this gives you an idea of why the `tab` parameter exists and what `__index` can be used for as a result.